# Xpath query with Java

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I need the right command for an Xpath query with Java

Good evening.
I'm here beacause I am not able to get the right result. I am trying to get UF1  UF2 UF3 and Steve Rogers in the next xml document. I am using Java and I am using the next expresion:  `XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("/modulos/modulo[@m='M01']/alumno/nombre/text()");`

I get Steve Rogers only. If I write
`XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("/modulos/modulo[@m='M01']/alumno/nombre/UF1/UF2/UF3/text()");`

I don´t get anyting. Any idea? Thanks a lot. Regards

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<modulos>
    <modulo m="M01">
        <alumno>
            <nombre>Steve Rogers</nombre>
            <UF1>5.00</UF1>
            <UF2>3.00</UF2>
            <UF3>7.00</UF3>
        </alumno>
        <alumno>
            <nombre>Bruce Banner</nombre>
            <UF1>9.00</UF1>
            <UF2>8.50</UF2>
            <UF3>8.00</UF3>
        </alumno>
        <alumno>
            <nombre>Tony Stark</nombre>
            <UF1>9.00</UF1>
            <UF2>9.00</UF2>
            <UF3>9.00</UF3>
        </alumno>
    </modulo>
    <modulo m="M02">
        <alumno>
            <nombre>Bruce Banner</nombre>
            <UF1>10.00</UF1>
            <UF2>7.75</UF2>
            <UF3>6.00</UF3>
        </alumno>
    </modulo>
    <modulo m="M03">
        <alumno>
            <nombre>Bruce Banner</nombre>
            <UF1>8.50</UF1>
            <UF2>6.50</UF2>
            <UF3>5.00</UF3>
        </alumno>
        <alumno>
            <nombre>Tony Stark</nombre>
            <UF1>8.00</UF1>
            <UF2>10.00</UF2>
            <UF3>9.00</UF3>
        </alumno>
    </modulo>
</modulos>
```

Answer (score 0):

All requested elements are children of `alumno`. This XPath gets the values

```
//modulo[@m="M01"]/alumno[nombre[.="Steve Rogers"]]/*/text()
```

Or

```
//modulo[@m="M01"]/alumno[1]/*/text()
```

Or

```
//modulo[@m="M01"]/alumno[1]/descendant::*[local-name()="nombre" or starts-with(local-name(),"UF")]/text()
```

Comment: Nothing at this moment is working yet. :(

Comment: @Lookingforaanswer... Add the rest of the code to the answer. How is ` XPathExpression` used.

Answer (score 0):

The slash (`/`) represents a parent-child relationship.

`/modulos/modulo` means “all `modulo` elements which are children of the root `modulos` element.”

`alumno/nombre/UF1/UF2/UF3` means “a UF3 element which is a child of a UF2 element which is a child of a UF1 element which is a child of a nombre element which is a child of an alumno element.”  In other words, your XPath is looking for this:

```
<modulos>
    <modulo m="M01">
        <alumno>
            <nombre>
                <UF1>
                    <UF2>
                        <UF3>7.00</UF3>
                    </UF2>
                </UF1>
            </nombre>
        </alumno>
        <alumno>
            <nombre>
                <UF1>
                    <UF2>
                        <UF3>8.00</UF3>
                    </UF2>
                </UF1>
            </nombre>
        </alumno>
        <alumno>
            <nombre>
                <UF1>
                    <UF2>
                        <UF3>9.00</UF3>
                    </UF2>
                </UF1>
            </nombre>
        </alumno>
    </modulo>
```

Obviously, this isn’t what you want.  You want the text of each child element in the `alumno` element.  The easiest way to do that is:

```
xpath.compile("/modulos/modulo[@m='M01']/alumno/*/text()");
```

The `*` means “an element with any name.”  The above expression is safe as long as you can be sure that the only element children of `alumno` will be nombre, UF1, UF2, and UF3.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer, all the answers here. I see a lot of effort. Nothing is working yet but i believe it is for my xpath version.